# How often is $1+\prod_{k=1}^n p_k$ not prime?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, primorial

How often is $1+\prod_{k=1}^n p_k$ is not prime?,wkere $p_k$ is k'th prime
consider that $2\times3\times5\times7\times11\times13+1=59\times509 = 30031$ is this one off or, are there infinitely many composites of the form $1+\prod_{k=1}^n p_k$?

Comment: Is not prime or is prime?

Comment: @Alizter : It seems more often it is prime, so "is not prime" I guess is better

Comment: Highly Related: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primorial_prime

Comment: It seems [A014545](http://oeis.org/A014545) is extremely relevant. Also it seems such numbers are called [Euclid Numbers](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EuclidNumber.html). And judging that one of the references is "Unsolved problems in number theory" I speculate that this is **still an open problem**.

Comment: I am pretty sure that this is quite rarely prime not often. I'd assume it is only slightly more often prime than a random number of that size would be prime. A guess could be there are roughly about $(\log n)^2$ primes among the first $n$ such numbers; but this is really just a guess.

Comment: @Arjang the question edited by Alex M. please check!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Define $p_n\#=p_1\cdots p_n$.  This is called the *[primorial](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Primorial.html)* of $p_n$ (like a factorial, but multiplying together only primes).

Prime numbers of the form $p_n\# \pm 1$ are called *[primorial primes](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimorialPrime.html)*.  Along a similar vein, *[Euclid Numbers](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EuclidNumber.html)* are of the form $p_n\#+1$ (not necessarily prime).

Thus, your question is: "How many prime Euclid Numbers are there?"  The Wolfram Mathworld article says:

> The largest known Euclid number is $E_{13494}$, and it is not known if there are an infinite number of prime Euclid numbers (Guy 1994, Ribenboim 1996).

Regarding composite Euclid numbers, [this comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/45742/are-there-an-infinite-number-of-prime-euclid-numbers#comment109952_45742) by François Brunault on MathOverflow says:

> According to Ribenboim (The little book of big primes, page 3), it is also not known whether there exist infinitely many composite Euclid numbers. Such questions are often very difficult to tackle.

**Summary:** There are many known prime Euclid Numbers ([A014545](http://oeis.org/A014545) is a list of $n$ such that $E_n$ is prime), but it is not known if there are infinitely many such primes.  There are also many known composite Euclid Numbers, but it is not known if there are infinitely many.